# Can't update multiple rows with $wpdb query

Tags: php, query, wpdb

it seems that I cannot update multiple rows to change the post_type of posts having a specific tag.

I follow different method, even if it seems the good one is this one :

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'editorial_post' WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = post AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'editorial'");
var_dump($result);
```

`Var_dump()` always returns a null result. Can someone tell me where I'm wrong ? Thank you very much.

Comment: From your code, you aren't storing the return value of query to `$result`

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, but the results give `boolean false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$wpdb->query()` returns number of rows affected by the query. It's returning `NULL` indicates that there is an error in your query.

The problem with your query is that you are updating `$wpdb->posts` table, but the condition depends on `$wpdb->postmeta` table. You have to join these tables for the query to work.

Another problem is that you have to place the post inside quote

```
$wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
```

Try the following query

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts
                        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
                            ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
                        SET $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'editorial_post'
                        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
                            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag'
                            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'editorial'");
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't answer earlier. I'll give it a try soon. Thanks